# Drupal AHAH Callback never called

Tags: ajax, routes

I'm having trouble with something incredibly simple: I want to count the number of rows I will export, before exporting it. For this I have a button "count" that on every click calls a php function and returns the counting. The problem I'm having is that Drupal never manages to get in the callback-function I specified.

Here is my code:

```
function monetisation_menu() {

    $items = array();

    $items['monetisation'] = array (
            'title' => '_Monetisation Export',
            'page callback' => 'monetisation_page',
            'access arguments' => array (
                    'access content'
            ),
            'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    );

    $items['monetisation/js_page'] = array (
            'title' => 'AHAH Monetisation callback',
            'page callback' => 'monetisation_js',
            'access arguments' => array (
                    'access content'
            ),
            'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );

    return $items;
}
```

My button:

```
$form['count_button'] = array (
            '#type' => 'button',
            '#value' => 'Count Selected Range',
            '#ahah' => array (
                    'event' => 'click',
                    'path' => 'monetisation/js_page',
                    'wrapper' => 'counting_msg-wrapper',
                    'effect' => 'fade',
                    'progress' => array(
                            'type' => 'throbber',
                            'message' => 'Please wait while we process your request...'
                    ),
            ),
    );
```

And my PHP Function:

```
function monetisation_js(){

    $form_state = $_POST;

    $monetisation = new monetisation();
    $params = array();

    _cleaningForm($form_state);
    $params['values'] = $form_state;
    $arrAttributes = _fillAttributesArray($params);

    $result = $monetisation->searchByAttributesArr($arrAttributes, _getAttributes(), false);
    $selected_count = $result;

    $data = "You have selected $selected_count records";
    drupal_set_message($data);

    drupal_json(array('status' => TRUE, 'data' => $data));
}
```

When I try it, I get an alert with "An error occured" followed with the html code of the page... Somebody Help me?